# How to calculate a recursive structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures, syntax

Would you show me how can we calculate a recursive value?

for example the following recursive function:

```
int rec (int n)
{
    if (n==1) return (1);
    else  
        return (rec(n-1) + rec(n-1));
}
```

Is there any general clue to solve these type of problems?

Comment: I don't understand your question. "This is one kind of data structure question." - I don't see any data structure...

Comment: The question is "can u pls do my homework for me?".

Comment: To calculate recursive rec(5) in this code, throw it in your main function and cout the return value..

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written a little program to compute `rec(5)` and print the result? Have you tried executing it by hand? Or was your first and only thought to ask us at stackoverflow to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well lets start by writing this as

```
int rec (int n)
{
  if (n==1) return (1);
  else  
    return (2 * rec(n-1));
}
```

As `a+a = 2a`

Next we see that is multiplying 2 together `n-1` times and on the nth time it is returning 1.

Therefore this is equivalent to 2^(n-1)

This means that `rec(5) = 2^(5-1) = 2^4 = 16`

Note: the form that I have above is also far more efficient than the one you had since I only calculate `rec(n-1)` `rec(n-2)` and so on only once (linear recursion). Where as with your function each is calculated exponentially many times (exponential recursion). This means that while my function scales fairly well, yours is basically unusable for anything larger than 100.

Comment: Its not 2*(n-1) its 2 multiplied together n-1 times

Comment: ok,so how we can solve the problem with two entrance element;for example:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cjGUuDXB for F(3,6),sorry for missing the comment!